# Difference in partitioned and non-partitioned table in terms of vertical join in q kdb

Tags: kdb

I have two non-partitioned tables:

```
q)s:([] date:(2019.07.01;2019.07.01;2019.07.02;2019.07.01;2019.07.05); co:`a`b`f`b`c)
q)t:([] date:(2019.07.01;2019.07.01;2019.07.02;2019.07.01;2019.07.07); co:`a`b`e`b`d)
```

In above table when I run below query it works perfectly fine.

```
q)select distinct co from s,t where date within 2019.07.01 2019.07.02
co
--
a
b
f
e
```

I have tables with same name which are partitioned by date, when I try to run same query on partitioned tables I get below error:

```
ERROR: 'par 
(trying to update a physically partitioned table)
```

1. Why do we get above error in partitioned tables?
2. What is the optimized approach to get similar output as we got in non-partitioned tables?

One solution to for 2 which I feel as brute-force is:

```
select distinct co from((select distinct co from s where date within 2019.07.01 2019.07.02),select distinct co from t where date within 2019.07.01 2019.07.02)
```

Comment: It's inadvisable to be partitioning on a pre-existing column. I'm assuming you wish for the tables to be spread over the specified dates, and there not to be two date columns when viewing in a partitioned database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are only including the date name in the source tables to assist in queries. A date partitioned table will generate the virtual date column from the hdb structure, you shouldn't include it in the actual table being written to.

> 1. Why do we get above error in partitioned tables?

**There is no way to avoid having to access the data of a partitioned table except through an initial a select statement.**. In this case you are directly trying to perform a `,` operation to the `s` and `t` tables

> 2. What is the optimized approach to get similar output as we got in non-partitioned tables?

In general, there may be a trade-off between the table size and the nature and frequency of the operations, sometimes it may be worth bringing the table into memory for frequent joins, or creating a top-level flat table with the relevant subset of data.

If this is just a generalized test case for larger operations then something along the following would be ideal

```
distinct raze {select distinct co from x where date within 2019.07.01 2019.07.02} each `s`t
```

This performance is not very different from your own query however, it's just a bit more succinct.